# Why does my Linux system have both private address and APIPA (link-local) assigned address on IPv4 interface

Tags: linux, networking, ipv4

On Linux Kernel 4.19.94+, I could see IPv4 private and link-local address assigned to the interface eth0 as shown below.  My understanding is that Automatic Private IP Addressing (APIPA) IP address (169.254.0.0/16) is only assigned when no IP address is allocated by DHCP server.

According to Bill Manning's [Documenting Special Use IPv4 Address Blocks spec](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-manning-dsua-06.txt):

> 169.254.0.0/16 has been ear-marked as the IP range to use for end node
> auto-configuration when a DHCP server may not be found. As such, network
> operations and administrators should be VERY aggressive in ensuring that
> neither route advertisements nor packet forwarding should occur across
> any media boundaries. This is true for the Internet as well as any
> private networks that use the IP protocols. End node administrators
> should be aware that some vendors will auto-configure and add this
> prefix to the nodes forwarding table. This will cause problems with
> sites that run router discovery or deprecated routing protocols such as
> RIP.

Following the above information, please can someone clarify the following:

**What causes 169.254.0.0/16 assignment on Linux version 4.19.94 when DHCP server has successfully assigned an IPv4 address?**

This is found to cause problems while sending broadcast messages.
How can this assignment of link-local be disabled when a private IP address is assigned to the interface?

Does this assignment causes duplicate network packets or increases network overhead, especially when using SSDP protocol or other service protocol.

```
eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1492 qdisc mq qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1c:2b:13:06:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.196.187/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope link eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.0.20/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::21c:2bff:fe13:62f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Something on your system setup (whichever distro you use) is wrong. This has nothing to do with the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

The above behaviour is caused by having the assignment "LinkLocalAddressing=yes" in Network section of `systemd/network/10-eth0.network` configuration.

This is clearly a bug with systemd network; details of this bug can be viewed here
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/13316 ;

Due to the current systemd bug, it would not be possible to have IPV4LL (IPV4 Link-Local Address)  address assigned when no DHCP server is found.

If `LinkLocalAddressing=fallback` is set then DHCP client will stop listening to DHCP server after assigning IPV4LL address. This violates `RFC 3927 (Ref https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-dhc-dna-ipv4-01).` This would imply when DHCP server is back online, previously assigned IPV4LL address will not get dropped and new address from DHCP server will never be assigned to the client.